# PHP Comet cause page reload slow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, comet

Hi I am tring to implement the comet with PHP and jquery. The comet is started on every page load. However it cause loading of any page in the website become very slow like 10 seconds, it seem to be waiting for the previous request to the server to die() at the if($elapse > 10)
But if a ajax connection connection is aborted, isn't the PHP should stop executing furher ? Any idea why reloading page become slow ?

```
function getPendingCheckin()
    {
        ignore_user_abort(false);
        $iCreatedDate =  $this->input->post("iLastCreateDate");

        $aCheckin = [];
        $prev = time();
        while(! $aCheckin )
        {
            $aCheckin = $this->getData();

            if($aCheckin || connection_aborted() == 1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                sleep(1);
                $elapse = time() - $prev;
                if($elapse > 10)
                {
                    die();
                }
            }
        }

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($aCheckin);
    }
```

Javascript

```
        $(window).ready(function(){
             var iLastCreateDate =  $('#iLastCreateDate').val();

             function startGetPendingCheckin()
             {
                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "/kc/comet/getPendingCheckin",
                       data: 'iLastCreateDate=' + iLastCreateDate,
                       error : function(msg)
                       {
                           //alert("Error get pending checkin");
                       },
                       success :function(o)
                       {
                           if(o)
                           {
                               //process data
                           }

                           startGetPendingCheckin();
                       }
                   });
             }

            startGetPendingCheckin();
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

No, php execution is not (always) aborted. I noticed that on heavy scripts runned on local machine.

You may fail to run 2 parallel request to php scripts due to not closed session. Usually it is auto-closed after termination of the script. With default behavior (sessions in lockable files, no manual closing) it is not possitble to have 2 simultaneous requests from the same user — the latter would be blocked by the former and will wait for its termination.

You may close session as long as you checked everything about user authorization.